# How can I view my Updated Data in blade.php from Cookies without onpage loading?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5, cookies, cart

I'm working on a project called Online Food Order with laravel Framework. Here I am storing my data into cookie from menu after onclick add to cart. Now I want to show those data in may cart without on page loading. Because, if I load the page, it return me to the top, which is not user friendly. So how can I solve this problem...??

I just want to view the data immediately after clicking "Add To Cart" button.

Comment: Why do you write the data to Cookies? You have to be very careful if you write data to localStorage (this is where the cookies will be saved), as an example: if you don't validate prices on serverside, it would be possible to change price by changing localStorage data. I think it would be better to write this data to session or database. Anyway to show the data dynamically on page you just need JS and add the Data to DOM after click.

Comment: Okay. I can set my prices and datas to Session. But till now the question is, How can I show them in cart instantly...? When I'm pressing the button (Add to cart) for adding data into cart, the page is loading. and the page is automatically refreshing and got to top. Whis is very embarrassing.

Comment: Then most likely the click to the button will invoke a HttpRequest, this is HTTP default behaviour. Without seeing your code it is very hard to say whats happening there.